# Counting nulls and non-nulls from a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Pyspark on which I want to count the nulls in the columns and the distinct values of those respective columns, i.e. the non-nulls

This is the dataframe that I have

```
trans_date   transaction_id    transaction_id1
2016-01-01     1                  1
2016-01-01     2                 null
2016-01-01     null               3
```

I want to do the aggregation on the month and year and generate something like this

`| month | year | id_count_in_x_not_in_y | id_count_in_y_not_in_x | ids_in_x | ids_in_y |`

```
df.groupBy(F.month(F.col("trans_date")).alias("MONTH"), \
                            F.year(F.col("trans_date")).alias("YEAR")) \
  .agg(*(F.sum(F.col(c).isNull().cast("int")).alias(c) for c in columns))\
  .show()
```

This is what I have in terms of code, but it does not seem to be giving me good answers. Also, how should be doing the non-null counts in the same code.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, group by year and month. We can count the nulls and non-nulls per group in each column and sum them after converting to ints; that part is quite simple.

For the count of elements that appear in one column but not the other, we can use `collect_set`, which aggregates the unique elements into a single array, in conjunction with `array_except`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

result = (df
     .groupBy(F.year('date').alias('year'), F.month('date').alias('month'))
     .agg(F.sum(F.isnull('x').cast(IntegerType())).alias('x_null'),
          F.sum(F.isnull('y').cast(IntegerType())).alias('y_null'),
          F.sum((~F.isnull('x')).cast(IntegerType())).alias('x_not_null'),
          F.sum((~F.isnull('y')).cast(IntegerType())).alias('y_not_null'),
          F.collect_set('x').alias('x_unique'),
          F.collect_set('y').alias('y_unique'))
     .withColumn('x_not_in_y_count', F.size(F.array_except('x_unique', 'y_unique')))
     .withColumn('y_not_in_x_count', F.size(F.array_except('y_unique', 'x_unique')))
     .drop('x_unique', 'y_unique')
     .orderBy('year', 'month')
)
```

Given the following test data:

```
+----------+----+----+
|      date|   x|   y|
+----------+----+----+
|1991-01-01|null|   2|
|1991-01-02|   1|null|
|1991-01-03|   2|   3|
|1991-02-01|null|   1|
|1991-02-02|null|   2|
+----------+----+----+
```

This is the output:

```
+----+-----+------+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|year|month|x_null|y_null|x_not_null|y_not_null|x_not_in_y_count|y_not_in_x_count|
+----+-----+------+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|1991|    1|     1|     1|         2|         2|               1|               1|
|1991|    2|     2|     0|         0|         2|               0|               2|
+----+-----+------+------+----------+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this. I was struggling quite a bit while doing this. I just have one question, I already get the test data that you have given by doing an outer join. So wouldn't it be just a count of nulls for getting the `x_not_in_y_count ` & `y_not_in_x_count`

Comment: @ManasJani What do you join on? I made the test data myself. I'm sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: I just joined on the transactionids I have mentioned in question and then create a final dataframe. The end goal is basically getting the resulting data set in question.